# action overload in identityserver 4 api project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

i woudl add 2 api into the controller of net core 3.1 api project:

first one accept access_token as parameter, the other one, called whitout parameters, retrives token from headers.

this the controller:

```
[Route("entitlements")]
public class EntitlementsController : ControllerBase
{

    [Route("entitlements/get/{access_token}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] string access_token)
    {
        EntitlementsResult oResult = GetEntitlements(access_token);
        return new JsonResult(oResult);
    }

    [Route("entitlements")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var access_token = await GetAccessTokenFromHeaders();
        EntitlementsResult oResult = GetEntitlements(token);
        return new JsonResult(oResult);
    }
}
```

but i get 404 not found calling the action from a client with this code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetEntitlements()
{
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        string apiUrl = Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer:api");
        var content = await client.GetStringAsync($"{apiUrl}/entitlements");
        ViewBag.Json = content;
        return View("json");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both of the action and controller contains `[Route("entitlements")]` attribute,so the correct url should be:`{apiUrl}/[ControllerRoute]/[ActionRoute]`,change like below:

```
var content = await client.GetStringAsync($"{apiUrl}/entitlements/entitlements");
```